# as.Date / strptime format

Tags: r, date

What could be the problem? I don't seem to get why this had to be NA.

> as.Date("jan2012", format="%b%Y")
>
> [1] NA

I have also used **strptime** function and it is the same thing. I have been using this functions but I don't know they are not working this morning. Any insight as to why this is will be useful.

Comment: Also may be proble with locale try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` before  `paste0( "01",....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` include day also.  So, we need to `paste` with a day i.e. 01

```
as.Date(paste("jan2012", "01"), format="%b%Y%d")
#[1] "2012-01-01"
```

Comment: Ok, noted! Anyways didn't quite used to focus on that the fact that date characters I had been using had day component.

Answer (score 1):

"jan2012" isn't a date, it's a month.  You need to prefix the day you want, e.g.

```
as.Date(paste0("01", "jan2012"), format = "%d%b%Y")
```